# Flex Datagrid within repeater - Data bind warning

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

In my Flex app I am using a repeater to show a report on my database data.  On this report the user can "drill-down" on the data to show more detail.  In order to make this easier on the eye I have a header label and then a datagrid within the repeater.

Whilst this works perfectly, because the dataprovider for the datagrid comes from an array in the repeaters dataprovider, it is causing the following warning:

**Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "report"**

The warning is for this line:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgReport" dataProvider="{rptReport.currentItem.report}" rowCount="{rptReport.currentItem.report.length}">
```

Below is my code, if anyone has any suggestions for how I can get rid of the warning/do this properly they will be most welcome!

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable] private var reportProvider;

        private function report_Handler(event:ResultEvent):void {
            // Temp variables
            var currentHeader:String = "";
            var previousHeader:String = "";

            // Retrieve PHP array
            var reportPHP:Array = ArrayUtil.toArray(event.result);

            // Create Flex array
            var reportFlex:Array = [];
            var reportFlex_dataGrid:Array = [];

            // Loop through PHP array
            for(var i:int = 0; i < reportPHP.length; i++) {
                // Retrieve current header
                currentHeader = reportPHP[i].header;

                // Clear array
                if (currentHeader != previousHeader) {
                    reportFlex_dataGrid = [];
                }

                reportFlex_dataGrid.push({column1:reportPHP[i].column1, column2:reportPHP[i].column2, column3:reportPHP[i].column3});                               
            }

            // Add to repeater array
            if (currentHeader != previousHeader) {                          
                // Add to array
                reportFlex.push({header:reportPHP[i].header, report:reportFlex_dataGrid});
            }

            // Store previous headers
            previousHeader = reportPHP[i].header;

            // Add to combobox data provider
            reportProvider = new ArrayCollection(reportFlex);
        }                       
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Repeater id="rptReport" dataProvider="{reportProvider}">
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Spacer height="5"/>

        <mx:Label id="lblHeader" text="{rptReport.currentItem.header}"/>

        <mx:DataGrid id="dgReport" dataProvider="{rptReport.currentItem.report}" rowCount="{rptReport.currentItem.report.length}">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column1" dataField="column1"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column2" dataField="column2"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column3" dataField="column3"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:VBox>  
</mx:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "report"

Your dataProvider is `rptReport.currentItem.report`. Of this, `rptReport`, being an mxml element, is `Bindable`. The `currentItem` property of the `Repeater` component is also declared to be `Bindable`. The `report` property of the current item is not bindable - current item itself is just an object. Through this warning Flex is saying that if you alter the `report` of an already assigned object to something else, it won't be automatically reflected in the data grid.

In most cases you can safely ignore this type of warnings.

When you say `x="{a.b.c.d}"` in mxml, the guarantee is that flex will detect changes made to any of the four items in the chain (a, b, c and d) and update the value of `x`. In other words, `x` will change when `a` or `a.b` or `b.c` or `c.d` is changed. For this to work, Flex expects that all those four are declared bindable. If it finds any of these items to be not bindable, it will throw a warning. A property is bindable if it was declared using mxml or if it was declared with the `[Bindable]` metadata tag in ActionScript.

In most cases, one would be interested only in the changes to `a` or `a.b`. In your example, changes happen only when `HTTPService` is resend, in which case the dataProvider itself will change.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, a little off-topic, but having a grid in a repeater sounds really busy. If you want to have a drill-down, pop it up or put it in a pane that's only visible in that mode.

Visually, the repeater is a pattern which the user can internalize. A grid inside that pattern is a lot harder to deal with. Scrolling the grid vs. scrolling the repeater will likely be frustrating, let alone Tab navigation.

Logistically, you are creating a lot of in-memory UI. I would worry about performance.

Consider using a List with a custom Item renderer instead of a repeater. I still would not put a grid in there, but it's worth the effort.

Cheers